# Barplot for volume per year doesn't show all year

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x <- structure(list(year = structure(c(2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017)), value = c(0,11,20,31,1000,10,500,161,20,3)), .Names = c("year", "value"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

I try to make a barplot using this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(year, value, fill=year)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

My problems are:
The x-axis with years have this format 2007.5 (they have the month .5 but I would like to have only the year).
I would like to have in x-axis all years from 2008 and see all years not every 2 years as it is now.

Is there any possible way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `year` is `numeric`, it creates numeric axis.

You can fix this by replacing `year` with `as.character(year)`

```
ggplot(x, aes(as.character(year), value, fill=year)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can impose discrete break values with `scale_x_continuous`:

```
ggplot(x, aes(year, value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=2008:2017)
```

[image]